# Caching views in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, caching, iframe, ember.js

I'm checking out Angularjs and ember and want to know if ember has the ability to cache views rather than just load/reload them. If I have tab with template "abc.html" and another tab with template "def.html" and another tab with template "ghi.html" can I create divs to be loaded within the same view space (div) and initially load the div but then just show/hide divs as I go from tab to tab. In other words preserve context so that if I'm on tab1 and scrolling half way down the page then click on tab 2 and start data entry and then go to tab 3 and state music I can go back to tab 1 and continue scrolling while tab 3 continues to play music and then click on tab 2 and continue where I left off working on my data entry then go back to tab 3 and change the music then back to tab 2 and coninue my data entry with the cursor where I left off? I did this with just javascript and I frames but am hoping I can do with with emberjs? Basically the caching of view content in a div and/or iframe and shown/hidden and never reloaded. what I had done is simply keep a list template url names and their serial#id then how the active div and show the target div by id. No target found? load it, add to set then display. I would think Ember should have such a facility or it could be extended or a Domain Injection interface could facilitate it?

Is this currently possible with Emberjs? --- thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure, what you describe is certainly doable with Ember.  You can use `ContainerView` and manage the child views programatically.  See http://emberjs.com/guides/views/manually-managing-view-hierarchy/